# How can I change font shape from small caps to italics without merging shapes?

Tags: fonts

After a version change, I now have a version of LaTeX in which `\itshape` appears not to override `\scshape` but rather causes LaTeX to try to merge the two and produce text in small-caps italic (`scit`).  I simply want italic, no small caps.

I've consulted *LaTeX 2e Font Selection* (`fntguide.pdf`) but it simply states that `\itshape` and `\scshape` are both shapes (November 2020, page 7) and does not say anything about merging or how to prevent it.

The following MWE demonstrates my issue:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

Text in {\scshape small caps and \itshape italics}.

\end{document}
```

I need to know what additional command to put in front of `\itshape` so that the font-selection engine will try to find shape `it` and not shape `scit`.

I am using TexLive 2020.20210202-3 from the new Debian stable (Bullseye) version. Running `xelatex --version` produces `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)`

Comment: Use `\upshape\scshape`.

Comment: @Davislor can you add an answer so I can accept it?  And maybe explain why it works?

Comment: This could be related to [ltnews31.pdf](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf) (cf. *Improvements to LaTeX’s font selection mechanism (NFSS)*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to Fix This

Use `\upshape\scshape` if you need to switch to upright small caps, or `\itshape\ulcshape` if you need to switch to italics without small caps.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

Text in {\scshape\itshape italic small caps},
{\itshape italics and \upshape\scshape upright small caps},
{\scshape small caps and \itshape\ulcshape italics}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus serif sample]

I could not reproduce your problem on my box, until I switched to a font that has italic small caps.

If you need backward compatibility with the older packages that never defined `\ulcshape`, add the line to your preamble, after loading your packages:

```
\providecommand\ulcshape\relax
```

#### Why This is Happening

Either you recently switched to a font that does have italic small caps, or a package you’re loading was recently updated to load `fontaxes`.

You might have been specifying italic small caps for years and never noticed, because you loaded a font that doesn’t have italic small caps and have been ignoring the warning message

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/scit' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/it' instead on input line 7.
```

The `fontaxes` package splits the “shape” axis into a primary axis (upright, italic, slanted, upright italic, etc.) and a secondary axis (small caps on or off).  It redefines the `\itshape` and `\scshape` commands to combine instead of override each other.  The `fontspec` package loads `fontaxes`.  So do many legacy font packages.

Comment: Ah, brilliant.  It's `fontaxes` exactly, loaded by `fontspec` after an upgrade to Debian Bullseye.  I noticed exactly because I started getting those warning messages, which I had never gotten before.